# Rails search in db with different fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 5 select's in my html code. I send them to controller, but for example some of them could be empty (default value is 0), so for example in some case i need to search only via `params[:size]`  is some case only via `params[:capacity]` and in other `params[:size] and params[:capacity]` both as well... But how do to this? how to operate with find etc?
now i have something like this:

```
size = "*"+params[:akbsize]+"*"
    @accums = Accumulator.find(:all, :conditions => ["MATCH(description) AGAINST (? in boolean mode)", size])
    cap = "*"+params[:akbcapacity]+"*"
    @accums2 = Accumulator.find(:all, :conditions => ["MATCH(description) AGAINST (? in boolean mode)", cap])
```

But how to do as i described? Is it good to do here with metasearch gem?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: @RadBrad 3.2.8, but is it necessary?

Comment: Just curious,  your using the old style (:condition=>...) as opposed to the new AREL stuff,  i.e.  Accumulator.where("MATCH(description)...").   I asked cause I was gonna post an answer,  but then realized it's probably best to look into a metasearch gem.

Comment: @RadBrad ok, please do with AREL stuff, and with metasearch)

Comment: @RadBrad so where you have lost?

Comment: Should I show you the way I do a cheesy metasearch in my app?

Comment: @RadBrad, yes will be a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make method for it like so:

```
class Accumulator
  def self.by_size(size)
    if size
      where("description LIKE ?", "%#{size}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end

  def self.by_capacity(capacity)
    if capacity
      where("description LIKE ?", "%#{capacity}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Then on your controller:

```
@accums = Accumulator.by_size(params[:size]).by_capacity(params[:capacity])
```

This would accomplish what u want. I think that the method all wouldn't be necessary at all.

=)

Comment: i dont have any fields like size or capacity... i have description... and i must search on this field...

Comment: Well, is the same bro, u just had to change the field name. Anyway, i updated my answer to reflect your needs. =)

Comment: my mistake, all is ok, simple chanhe field :D:DD

Comment: added methods to model... undefined method `by_size' for #<Array:0xb665c8c>

Comment: heh, have try... but then get undefined method `by_size' for #<Class:0xb692674> also try to add to controller... nothing...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19347/discussion-between-paulo-henrique-and-brabertaser1992)

Answer (score 0):

```
sterms = [params[:a],params[:b],params[:c]].select {|t| t}.join('%')
results = Accumulator.where("description like ?", "%#{sterms}%")
```

Or you could use boolean search like this

```
sterms = [params[:a],params[:b],params[:c]].select {|t| t}.map {|t| '+' + t}.join(' ')
results = Accumulator.where("MATCH(description) AGAINST( ? in boolean mode) ", sterms)
```

or if you are searching for a description where ANY of the params passed search terms will generate a match you'd do this:

```
sterms = [params[:a],params[:b],params[:c]].select {|t| t}.join(' ')
results = Accumulator.where("MATCH(description) AGAINST( ? in boolean mode) ", sterms)
```

These assume that the params are simply absent, i.e. nil.  If there is a specific value you want to use to indicate empty,  change the .select, i.e.

```
sterms = [params[:a],params[:b],params[:c]].select {|t| t != "0"}.join('%')
```

As you can see,  I could keep going with various permutations and combinations of search logic,  which is why I'd recommend finding a metasearch gem of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [Ransack gem](https://github.com/ernie/ransack), which more or less solves the problem of creating complex search forms.